# Termset, Termstore, Term meaning

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata

I am confused with sharepoint `term/termstore/terset` meanings.
I have termstore like below image, can anyone help me to clarify what is termstore what is termset ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Term Store** - is the top level in this hierarchy and corresponds whole Managed Metadata Service Application.

**Term Group** - is group of term sets inside the term store. "Site Collection - ..." in your picture.

**Term Set** - is collection of terms inside term group, where specific terms are stored. "My Term Set" in your picture.

**Term** - is one term inside term set, for example "My Term 2" in your picture. Term can also have child terms, like "My Term 1" in your picture.

Answer (score 1):

**Term Store** is the place where you store and manage your Terms and Term Set. It is stored in the Database of the Managed Meta Data service. You can manage the Term Store using the Term Store Tool. The picture you shared in the question...You are at Term Store Management tool.

A **term** is a word or a phrase that can be associated with an item in SharePoint Server 2013. A **term set** is a collection of related terms. You can specify that a column must contain a term from a specific term set.

**For example,** imagine that you are organizing a conference. Each conference session is assigned a room, and the large sessions are also assigned an overflow room, in which attendees who do not fit into the primary room can watch the session broadcast on large screens. You decide to track all of the sessions and their associated details in a SharePoint list.
To keep track of the sessions and their conference rooms, you would:

1. Create a term set that is named “Conference rooms” to represent all
   of the available rooms.
2. Add a term to the term set for each conference room
3. Create a content type called “Session.”
4. Add two new columns to the content type: “Room” and “Overflow room.”
5. Specify that the value of each of these columns must come from the
   "Conference rooms" term set.
6. Create a list of sessions.

In this example, when you add a session to the list, you provide values for the Room and Overflow room. If you later reserve an additional room at the conference center, you would add a new term to the Conference rooms term set, and it would become a valid value for the two columns.

Get more info here: [Overview of managed metadata](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424402.aspx)